# How Do I Make My Logo Stay Left While Resizing Browser Using Navbar-Brand In Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I resize my browser, the logo keeps moving or snapping around. I want to pin it with a margin of 15px to the left until it reaches the 768px media query (because i set my logo to snap tocenter when in that breakpoint). How do I do this? Below is my code.

```css
body {
  background-color: #222;
}
.navbar {
  min-height: 56px;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #333;
  border-color: #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 0px black;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 0px black;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #999;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.navbar-brand {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #d2d2d2;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="Buffing Your Gaming Experience">
  <meta name="author" content="Raphola">
  <link rel="icon" href="">

  <title>Primera Games</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
          <img alt="Logo" src="logo.png">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="contact">CONTACT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the left `left: 50%;` from your media queries in `.navbar-brand`

So it should be..

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove left:50% here "@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-brand{  }

if you want margin more on left side of logo use the left style property.

```css
body {
  background-color: #222;
}
.navbar {
  min-height: 56px;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #333;
  border-color: #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 0px black;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 0px black;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #999;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.navbar-brand {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-brand {
   
    
    position: absolute;
  }
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #d2d2d2;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="Buffing Your Gaming Experience">
  <meta name="author" content="Raphola">
  <link rel="icon" href="">

  <title>Primera Games</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
          <img alt="Logo" src="logo.png">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="contact">CONTACT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the position absolute or you can over ride the media query by changing the left property

```
  @media(max-width: 767px){
    left:10%

}
```